# Box "Post as Guest" bug

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, asking-questions

the form "post as guest" have two text fields getting out of box, as you can see in this page 
[Why do movie posters use credit fonts that are hard to read?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51556/why-do-movie-posters-use-credit-fonts-that-are-hard-to-read)

**and here is a screenshot:**

> [image]

or in more detail

> [image]

OS: Windows 7
Browser: Chrome 34.0.1823.4 canary / Google Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m / Chrome 37

Comment: Can't reproduce, Windows 7 with Chrome 32 here as well. Make sure you don't have some browser extension/add-on that might be causing this.

Comment: my chrome canary have same issue, and are clear, without add-ons

Comment: Chrome canary is **not supported**. We do not support browsers in their alpha/beta stages.

Comment: OK. but both are equal at same issue, i only want help. thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this be [meta-tag:status-norepro] instead of [meta-tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @Oded [reproduced now in Chrome 37.0.2062.124](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6CTRD.png) can you please take a look again or at least remove the [meta-tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @scrblnrd3 it was declined based on the belief it's happening only in a non supported browser so the team had no plans to start supporting it. Now that it happens in latest major version, they will hopefully fix it at some point. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No-repro on Chrome 39 (dev) so wondering if it was a Chrome bug.

Comment: @hichris123 well, turns out it was a lucky shot, it happens only on http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask as far as I could see, and that was just a random site I visited. Now tried looking on 10 others and they are all fine.

Comment: @Oded looks like it's specific to http://rpg.stackexchange.com should I start a new bug report in its per meta site?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yeah, that's site specific enough to belong on their meta.