# Longer textfields in the "Post as a Guest" section

Tags: bug, design

The textfields in the "Post as a Guest" section could be made a bit more longer:

[image: Longer textfields]

And on [English Language & Usuage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), the textfields appear a bit too big on Firefox:

[image: Too long textfields]

while on Chrome, the textfields in EL&U overflows out of the box.

Comment: The overflow in Chrome is a known bug and fix [was declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219860/box-post-as-guest-bug).

Comment: @ShadowWizard "_turns out it was a lucky shot_" -- But it isn't _luck_ for me. I can reproduce this even now. I'm using Chrome, latest version, on android.

Comment: I know, reproduced too but it was declined since it is a bug in Chrome itself.