# StackExchange pages periodically have issues displaying in Chrome Canary

Tags: bug, status-declined

Periodically, every page I have open on the stackexchange.com domain has "issues displaying", according to Chrome.

About every 2 minutes or so, Chrome gives me the "Aw, Snap! There were issues displaying this web page..." error page for every page I have open under the domain. This includes chat.stackexchange, meta.stackexchange, and hardwarerecs.stackexchange (haven't checked others). Stack Overflow is fine, as is Super User.

Strikes me that it could be something to do with web sockets, though for chat to die as well is odd.

Chrome 49.0.2599.0 (Canary), revision c774f8f, Windows 10.

Comment: Well, you are using a developer version of the browser... what did you expect?

Comment: @Braiam Given that it's worked flawlessly since I last updated it last week, and only broke today without any browser changes, I ruled the browser out.

Comment: The ---one--- many times that Safari can be better than Chrome :D

Comment: If anything, I would close this as dupe of "which browsers are officially supported", not as off topic. Agree the current close reason is wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Chrome Canary is not supported by Stack Exchange, i.e. things can simply break there.

Oded give official stand in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219860/box-post-as-guest-bug#comment711739_219860):

> Chrome canary is **not supported**. We do not support browsers in their alpha/beta stages

Even the [official page on Google](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) clearly says:

> Be forewarned: it's designed for developers and early adopters, **and can sometimes break down completely**.

So really can't see how you think it's bug on SE side.

If you want to browse safely, use a stable browser.

Comment: See my comment on the question. I *did* consider that it might be my end, believe it or not, but ruled it out logically.

Comment: @ǝpoɔɟoʇɹɐ that's the thing... they can change something that fixes the site for everyone using a stable releases, but utterly breaks anything too edgy,

Comment: @ǝpoɔɟoʇɹɐ I get what you say, but what Braiam said is true. Bottom line, when using such a browser you should expect anything (client side) to break.